# move offset text position in polar plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to change the position of the offset text (see in the attached picture).

[image: Change Position of 'Scientific scale'-tick]

Is there a way to do this in matplotlib?

My code:

```
"""
Demo of a line plot on a polar axis.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r
r = r*1000000000
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r, color='b', linewidth=3)

ax.grid(True)

ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The text object is called the `offset_text`. On a polar plot, it is considered the offset text of the `yaxis`. You could move it using the `ax.yaxis.set_offset_position()` function. This only takes `left` or `right` as options. So, adding `ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('right')` would move it closer to where you want:

[image]

---

By request, here's that line in the full script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r
r = r*1000000000
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r, color='b', linewidth=3)

ax.grid(True)

ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('right')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see how you made this nice layout?

Comment: sure, but its exactly the same as in the question, just with the line I wrote in the answer added...

Comment: are you using LaTeX to get this layout?

Comment: by 'layout', do you really mean font?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, that is what I mean.

Comment: yes, I have the rc param `text.usetex : True` set in my `matplotlibrc` file. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html)